# Spatial join for two polygon files in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I have two polygon files. One is MSOA (area defined by UK Census) area and the other is area defined by a project purpose. Most of the project area/polygons are within the MSOA areas e.g. five MSOA areas go within one project area. This happens in most cases. But there are few cases where MSOA areas are divided by project areas.

I want to join these two polygons. So that I can have a table saying MSOA area 1 covers project area 1,2,3 and 5.

Now I understand there will be at least two different methods to follow. I did this in Mapinfo where the join command works with two/three different options such as 'within' 'consists' etc. Unfortunately, I don't have Mapinfo atm and only have access to QGIS. The attribute tables do not have anything common. So it needs to be a spatial join.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for:

> Join Attributes By Location

in the geoprocessing toolbox. You can set the geoprocessing toolbox to "advanced" for the same layout as the image below or you can simply search. [image]